# flutter_markdown with Firestore image crash

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm using `flutter_markdown: ^0.2.0` and I want to display an image saved on firebase firestorage.

If I try to display the markdown in my flutter widget:

```
class LessonScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LessonScreen({this.lesson});
  final Lesson lesson;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      body:     
     MarkdownBody(data: lesson.content));
  }
}
```

My app crash.

```
I/flutter (25385): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (25385): The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (25385): Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,
I/flutter (25385): https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname-db7de.appspot.com/o/image1.PNG?alt=media&amp;token=xxxx
```

I don't have this problem with other images, but I have it only with the images saved on firestorage.

**SOLVED**

I have seen that the url that doesn't work is:

```
alt=media&amp;token=xxxx
```

instead of

```
alt=media&token=xxxx
```

this is the [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/issues/58) to `flutter_markown` repository issue.

I hope this fix will be available sooner or later

Comment: Please add some code to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: By app crash you mean you are getting errors?

Comment: app crash means that the app is frozen and I can't do nothing: it's broken.

Comment: Does the image url work in a simple image widget?

Comment: Yes, it works as simple Image widget. Only in the markdown doesn't work.

Comment: I need to know the error you are getting. What is the error you see in the logs?

Comment: I don't think it is related to the markdown package. Could you add more code which encloses the markdown to your question?

Comment: Do other urls work other than firebase storage urls? For e.g `MarkdownBody(data: "![alt text](https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpg)"`

Comment: Yes...it works with imgur image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196189/discussion-between-10101010-and-ilbarra).

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403`  it means auth error.

You should check more detail about `firebase store`.
It's not about `markdown` stuff.

Comment: If I use the following code, everything works: `Image.network( 
'firebasestorage.googleapis.co…')`. It's about `markdown` stuff.

Comment: could you please show hole link parameter you input in the Image.network()?

Comment: I think your link get 403 is because it's private link, and you provide above which works is a public link.

Comment: How is possible that te same url works fine in Image.network and doesn't works if it is embedded in the markdown widget?

Comment: All the code is in my question. The variable `lesson.content` hold: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname-db7de.appspot.com/o/image1.PNG?alt=media&token=xxxx"

Comment: @ilBarra all I can say is it's permission problem.

Comment: Thank you @JerryZhou for your feedback and your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196204/discussion-between-ilbarra-and-jerryzhou).

Answer (score 0):

- I had the same issue the problem was with the permission in the `Firebase Storage` so I change my `Firebase Storage` permission.
  From

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

To this

```
allow read, write;
```